# Why after logout and redirect cookies still exists?

Tags: node.js, express

```js
router.get('/logout', isAuth, (req, res) => {
    res.clearCookie('jtoken')
    return res.redirect('/')
})

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    return res.send(req.cookies)
})
```

After logout and redirect to `'/'` I see that cookies still exists, but on the next request they will be destroyed?

Comment: Do you use express, or just node?

Comment: I use express...

Comment: how do you know that cookies still exist? Do you have the frontend part as well?

Comment: I just see that '/' returns me req.cookies or it doesn't matter?